# SAPUI5 Grid Table Batch Editing

Tags: sapui5

I am working with SAPUI5 Grid Table batch editing(Editable or non-editable cell). I am thinking about two options mentioned below but I am not sure if I can achieve this or is it even supported by Grid Table

1. I want to click on a grid cell and change the control from text to input so that I can edit record and save it later.
2. Keep input editable to false and by clicking the cell or input, whichever is easy, change input editable to true. I was trying this option but once the input editable is set to false no event gets fired on input so, therefore, can't change the state at all.

Also, I have noticed that setting editable to false on Table itself doesn't do anything at least in my case it is not doing anything.

Any help or guidance will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To use multiple type of controls you need to handle their specific events. Try setting hidden controls and handle their events to make them visible or not.

View

```
<VBox>
  <Link text="{OrderID}" press="onSFPressed" visible="true"/>
  <Input value="{OrderID}" submit="onSFSubmitted" change="onSFChanged" visible="false"/>
</VBox>
```

Controller

```
onSFPressed: function(oEvent){
    var oText = oEvent.getSource();
    var oInput = oEvent.getSource().getParent().getItems()[1];

    oText.setVisible(false);
    oInput.setVisible(true);
},

onSFSubmitted: function(oEvent){
    var oText = oEvent.getSource().getParent().getItems()[0];
    var oInput = oEvent.getSource();

    oText.setVisible(true);
    oInput.setVisible(false);
},

onSFChanged: function(oEvent){
    var oText = oEvent.getSource().getParent().getItems()[0];
    var oInput = oEvent.getSource();

    oText.setVisible(true);
    oInput.setVisible(false);
}
```

Here the snippet: https://plnkr.co/edit/nSMv3BZoifdQaqWYtZgM?p=preview

Comment: Thanks for your answer but smart field won't work for select or input with suggestions. Please correct me if I am wrong?

Comment: If you want to use different controls as inputs you should handle their specific events. I have edited my answer and snippet with a Show/Hide functionality. Take a look!!

Comment: I like this approach why I didn't think about it. Appreciate that I will change this a little bit but thanks for giving me the idea.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you need this feature only for the sake of visual representation (you don't wanna see the raw input in each grid table cell).

The easiest solution would be to use *sap.m.Input* control in each cell and play with CSS to fake the *sap.m.Text* if it is not focused.

I've create a simple example: http://jsbin.com/ziwoyel/edit?html,js,output

CSS:

```
 .myCustomInputClass input {
    border: 0;
    background: none;
  }
```

This is the most simple and lightweight solution.

If you really need switching between 2 controls, I would recommend creating a custom control, which encapsulates the logic of switching between 2 states (2 controls) based on focusing in/out events.

Comment: Is there anything supported by SAPUI5 out of the box for such functionality? Though having said that I really liked the idea of having a custom control.

Comment: Didn't get your point. There is a valid SAPUI5 API for creation of  custom controls (the approach was well-documented in api docs). What is the root cause of such requirement?

Comment: Sorry if I wasn't clear, I agree with your approach of using a custom control and I know it is a valid approach. What I mean by my above comment was is there any property or configuration within grid table that allow batch editing.